# jQuery: Trick or best practice to apply all the ready() rules to new elements (Not talking about live() or on())

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some standard plugins bindings on jQuery `ready()` function that works fine for all new requests. Now, as we add more and more ajax to the app, these new elements are left behind the initial bindings.

Example rules:

```
$(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: "cal.gif" })
               .blur(function (e) {
                   $(this).val(formatFecha($(this).val()));
               })
    $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').attr("tabindex", "-1");
    $(".decimalnumber").numpadDecSeparator({ separator: "," })
                   .numeric(",")
                   .focus(function () { if ($(this).val() == '0,00' || $(this).val() == '0') $(this).val(''); });
    $(".integernumber").numeric().focus(function () { if ($(this).val() == '0') $(this).val(''); });
    $(".spinner").spinner({ min: 0, max: 10000000 });
    $(".jbtn").button();

    .......
```

I'm **not** talking about the `live()` function to bind events, as this are not events.

Since I think this is fairly common I'm wondering how do you people do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a refined version of @Blazemonger code:

You just need to put to new elements a class name by convention.

```
    function initialize(parent) {
        $(parent + ' .date').datepicker({ showOn: 'button'})
        $(parent + ' .autocomplete').each(function (i, el) {
            addbuttonautocomplete(el);
        });

        ....
        // remove the class to avoid double initialization
        $(".newelements").removeClass('newelements');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize('body');
    });

    $.ajax({
        // url, data, etc.
        success: function() {
            initialize('.newelements');
        }
    });
```

Proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/ireguj

Answer (score 5):

Place those functions in a separate function of their own. Call THAT function on `document.ready` and any other time you need to reload things.

```
function initialize() {
    // do stuff;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
});

$.ajax({
    // url, data, etc.
    success: function() {
        initialize();
    }
});
```

Be aware that some plugins, such as slideshows that alter the DOM, may need you to call a `destroy` method or option before re-initializing them.

Comment: wouldn't that re-call and re-initialize stuff on all elements which were already initialized, possibly leading to trouble ?

Comment: Was thinking of that, but has to only apply to new elements (because some things cannot be initialized twice)

Comment: @jAndy Just added a remark about that. Some will, some won't, and only the developer can know which is which.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni If SOME code should not be re-initialized, then put THAT code in `document.ready` and not `initialize()`. You'll have to use your own judgment here.

Comment: We should be able to call `initialize('body')` and after that  `initialize('newdiv')`

Comment: @EduardoMolteni There are clearly many special cases which only you can resolve. Good luck doing so! Please come back to us if you have any specific issues you can't sort out.

Comment: ok, got that, just want to retrieve some ideas from the community

Comment: I've added a refined version of your code. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 3):

I use a javascript library called [TerrificJS](http://terrifically.org). It allows me to easily load html with ajax and initialize the javascript that goes with it on time. But it's not quite that simple. TerrificJS relies on naming conventions.

Let's say the ajax return the following html:

```
<div class="mod modMyInteractiveModule">Cool stuff, buttons etc here</div>
```

I then have a helper function that scans the html returned on **ajax success** and picks out all elements with the css class **mod** and **modX**. The helper checks if there is a javascript class named **X** or, staying with the example above **MyInteractiveModule**.

```
Tc.Module.MyInterActiveModule = function () {
    // Bindings go here
}
```

I hope I could shed some light, even if you don't want to use TerrificJS and implement your own solution. The TerrificJS example to this can be found on http://terrifically.org/api/sandbox/ under **Add new widgets dynamically**.

Comment: Good to know. Will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I would move all of the code specified in an init() function and call it on document.ready  and on ajax success/failure, depending on what i'm trying to do